# Magento controller method is not being called in rout

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to call another method exept index mothod of controller in url, its not being called in  magento. how can i call the other method of controller in the url. my rout is. localhost/sewingapis/categories/index/testingMethod.

My controller code is:

```
  class Product_Category_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {
        public function indexAction()
        {

            $parent = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();    
            $tree = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_tree');
            /* @var $tree Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree */

            $nodes = $tree->loadNode($parent)
                ->loadChildren($recursionLevel)
                ->getChildren();
            $tree->addCollectionData(null, false, $parent);

            $categoryTreeData = array();
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                $categoryTreeData[$node->getData('entity_id')] = $this->getNodeChildrenData($node);
            }

            //return $categoryTreeData;
            $response['status'] = true;
            $response['data'] = $categoryTreeData;
            echo json_encode($response);

        }

        function getNodeChildrenData(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $node)
        {
            $data = array(
                'title' => $node->getData('name'),
                'url'   => $node->getData('url_key'),
            );

            foreach ($node->getChildren() as $childNode) {
                if (!array_key_exists('children', $data)) {
                    $data['children'] = array();
                }

                $data['children'][$childNode->getData('entity_id')] = $this->getNodeChildrenData($childNode);
            }
            return $data;
        }

        public function getCatSubCatByProductId()
        {
          $categoryId = 10;    
          $products = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
                    ->getProductCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
          }

          public function testingMethod(){
            echo 'hello';
          }
    }
```

My config.xml.

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Product_Category>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Product_Category>
    </modules>  
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <category>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Product_Category</module>
                    <frontName>categories</frontName>
                </args>
            </category>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>

</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `Action` postfix in the method name same as added in index action.

```
 public function testingMethodAction(){
        echo 'hello';
 }
```

Comment: Its soloved my problem. Thanks Pankaj Pareek.